# Where can I see the task metrics in Spark

Tags: apache-spark

I have a simple spark code,I want to see the metrics about how many records are read on Spark Web UI, but I didn't find the metrics shows up in spark ui or  http://localhost:4040/metrics/json,

I would ask where I can find the metrics， thanks, I am using Spark 2.3.0

```
test("task metrics") {
    val spark = SparkSession
      .builder
      .appName("task metrics")
      .master("local[*]")
      .getOrCreate()

    spark.sparkContext.parallelize(1 to 100, 100).mapPartitions(iter => {
      //The metrics I want to see
      val metrics = TaskContext.get().taskMetrics().inputMetrics
      while (iter.hasNext) {
        metrics.incRecordsRead(1)
        iter.next()
      }
      Iterator.empty
    }).count()

    println("job is done")

    Thread.sleep(10*60*1000)

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try http://localhost:4040/jobs. Click on the job, you will see the input column. It shows size of input read in bytes. If you click further on appropriate stage where input is read, a column with name "Input Size / Records" will show size of inputs as well as number of records read.